# Passing console input from scanner into a java object, cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a student class which consist of first and last name methods and constructor. I need to create a method that passes console input and assign it to a student object and can print the full name and the first name separately in the main method.

Student Class

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

StudentName Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Your full name is " + getStudentFullName(newStudent));
        System.out.println("Your first name is " + getStudentFullName(firstName));  
    }
    
    public static void getStudentFullName(Student student){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your full name?");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        name = name.trim();
        int index1 = name.indexOf(" ");
        String firstName = name.substring(0,index1);
        String lastName = name.substring(index1 + 1);
        Student newStudent = new Student(firstName,lastName);
    }  
}
```

Update: Error messages

```
error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Your full name is " + getStudentFullName(newStudent));
symbol:   variable newStudent
location: class StudentName

error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Your first name is " + getStudentFullName(firstName));  
symbol:   variable firstName
location: class StudentName
```

Comment: What is the **complete** error message?  Please include all relevant details in your questions.

Comment: @StephenC added error.

Comment: OK ... so why is `newStudent` declared in `getStudentFullName`?   Declare it in the method where you use it.  Likewise, why are you using `firstName` in `main`?  It isn't declared in `main`.

Comment: Also ... look at `getStudentFullName` and understand it's purpose.  Then ask youtself, why are you trying to print the >>result<< of `getStudentFullName`?  It doesn't have a result.

Comment: I recommend that you read about [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/).  It is a technique that involves reading your own code, and understanding it ... by trying to explain it to an (imaginary) someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the getStudentFullName method in a wrong way.
in line `System.out.println("Your full name is " + getStudentFullName(newStudent));` where's the newStudent variable? you can have two approches : first you can define it in main method and pass it to `getStudentFullName` method and in this method change the passed argument instead of creating a new one as below :

```
public class StudentName {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student newStudent = new Student();
    System.out.println("Your full name is " + getStudentFullName(newStudent));
     
}

public static void getStudentFullName(Student student){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your full name?");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    name = name.trim();
    int index1 = name.indexOf(" ");
    String firstName = name.substring(0,index1);
    String lastName = name.substring(index1 + 1);
    student.setFirstName(firstName);
    student.setLastName(lastName);
}  
}
```

or you can return the `newStudent` from the `getStudentFullName` method as below:

```
public class StudentName {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your full name is " + getStudentFullName(newStudent));
     
}

public static Student getStudentFullName(Student student){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your full name?");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    name = name.trim();
    int index1 = name.indexOf(" ");
    String firstName = name.substring(0,index1);
    String lastName = name.substring(index1 + 1);
    Student newStudent = new Student(firstName,lastName);
    return newStudent;
}  
}
```

but in line `System.out.println("Your first name is " + getStudentFullName(firstName));` what is the firstName? if it is a String variable  you can't pass it to `getStudentFullName` because it accepts a variable of type Student as an argument not a String.

after all, it's better you put the code of getting the input form console in main method!